# É possível converter um ArrayList<Double> para ArrayList<Integer>?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Então galera, gostaria de saber se há e como fazer a conversão de um `ArrayList<Double>` em um `ArrayList<Integer>`?

Comment: Você foi rápido na edição hein

Comment: Malz galera, acabei colocando palavra errada no título.

Comment: É só fazer manualmente item por item.

Comment: É possível mas você perderá a precisão decimal do números

Comment: @Articuno, certo como eu faria então? Seguindo o exemplo do LINQ?

Comment: A resposta dele é a solução. Não tem como manter precisão decimal em inteiro, isso é regra básica da matemática

Comment: @ChristianGomesdaSilva Percebi que vc não tem nenhuma pergunta com resposta aceita. Só pra te avisar, você sempre pode aceitar uma resposta para suas perguntas, é só marcar o **V** do lado da resposta que deseja deixar como correta =D

Comment: @LINQ muito obrigado pela a dica, ainda não entendi muito bem como usar o stack de maneira correta.

Comment: @ChristianGomesdaSilva Aí jovem, a resposta atendeu o que você precisava? Precisa que eu melhore algo nela?

Answer (score 12):

Precisa fazer algo para que **todos os itens** da lista original retornem seu valor inteiro. Isso pode ser feito com o método [`intValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html).

Note que, obviamente, a parte decimal dos números será perdida.

Usando Java 8

```
List<Double> doubles = /* lista original */;

List<Integer> integers = doubles.stream() 
                                .map(d -> d.intValue())
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

[<sup>**Veja funcionando no Repl.it.**</sup>](https://repl.it/OGS3/0)

Em versões anteriores.

Note que a inferência de tipos do lado direito da declaração de genéricos só foi inserida no Java 7 — [vide documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html). Ainda assim, a resposta é válida para todas as versões inferiores, apenas é preciso trocar a instanciação do *ArrayList* de `new ArrayList<>()` para  `new ArrayList<Integer>()`.

```
List<Double> doubles = /* lista original */;

List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();

for(Double d : doubles) {
    integers.add(d.intValue());
}
```

<sup>[**Veja funcionando no Repl.it.**](https://repl.it/OGSm)</sup>